# Cordova app-release-unsigned.apk not working

Tags: android, cordova, release

My Cordova-generated app-debug.apk installs and works perfectly.

But when I then create my app-release-unsigned.apk using the cordova build android --release command, the release apk doesn't even install. I'd like to install and check the release apk before adding security software to it, signing it and then publishing it.

Is there something I need to do AFTER creating my app-debug.apk but BEFORE I use the cordova build android --release command?

I'm using the latest versions of Cordova and Android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only install signed apps on an android device.

Even a debug version of an app is signed with a debug key. You will need to sign your APK with [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner) after you generate it.

Comment: Ah - thanks. Can I do this? (1) Add security software to debug apk. (2) Create unsigned release apk (using "cordova build android ---release"). (3) Create keystore (using "$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore MYAPP.keystore -alias 
MYAPP -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
"). (4) Sign (using "$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore MYAPP.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk MYAPP"). (5) Rename (using "zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk NEWNAME.apk"). (6) Upload to Play Store.

Comment: @JesusGirl2000 I'm not sure what your "security software" is supposed to do and I assume that you don't have to integrate it in a debug APK. So step 1 seems redundant to me, since you create a release APK in (2) anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Hoffman. Sorry - should have been clearer: by "security software" I mean whatever is done/added to/integrated with my debug app by the company that's providing its obfuscation protection. Are steps (2) to (6) correct?

Comment: @JesusGirl2000 I would do it like this:
1. Add obfuscation. 2. Generate release APK. 3. Rename it (no need to use zipalign for this). 4. use `apksigner` to sign the APK.